Size of a surface in WebAR
I need to detect a surface (like a wall) and find its size, so I can add some mesh with the size of the detected wall.
Is there any libraries or tools that I can use for finding size of the surface?
Im using threejs library with web-xr for detecting the surface I use hit testing, but I need help with detecting the size

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
